# Radio Buttons Don't Submit with Number Field Present

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, input, paypal

I am trying to create a simple web form that consists of a couple of checkbox buttons and a number field. It's submitted with a button. For some reason, when the number input box is present, the form will submit 0.00. If I type something into the number field, it will pass whatever I type, but if I select one of the numbers and leave the input field blank, it submits 0.00. I can't seem to figure out why.

If I remove the code , everything works fine.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
      <div class="donation_container">
        <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_donations"> 
        <input name="business" type="hidden" value="info@***.org"> 
        <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Donation">
        <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1"> 
        <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1"> 
        <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD"> 
        <input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00"> 
        <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="US"> 
        <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-DonationsBF"> 
        <div class="donate_call_to_action">
          <div class="donate_call_to_action_text">Become ***
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="donation_buttons">
          <label class="donation_label"> 
            <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="1000.00">
            <div>$1000</div>
          </label>
          <label class="donation_label">
            <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="500.00">
            <div>$500</div>
          </label>
          <label class="donation_label">
            <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="100.00">
            <div>$100</div>
          </label>
          <label class="donation_label">
            <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="50.00">
            <div>$50</div>
          </label>
          <div class="custom_donation">
            <i>$</i>
            <input name="amount" type="number">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="donation_button">
        <button type="submit" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit">Donate</button> 
        <img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0">
      </div>
    </form>
```

**UPDATE:**

It turns out I can only submit a value with the name=amount attribute, once. Having an input type=number field AND checkboxes causes the donate button to submit multiple "amounts". Even if the input box was empty, it would submit a null value, for instance, amount=50.00&amount= The solution was a little jQuery to turn off the name attribute for the input field. If the input field is either 0 or the length of the value is 0, the script will strip out the name attribute.

```html
<script>
      (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
           alert($(this).serialize());
           event.preventDefault();
         });
        });
        $("#other_amount").removeAttr("name"); //on load, remove the name attribute. Default action.
        $( "#other_amount" ).blur(function() {
         if(($(this).val().length == "0") || ($(this).val() == "0")){
            $(this).removeAttr("name");
            } else {
             $(this).attr("name", "amount");
            }
        });
      })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your number field has the same `amount` name as the checkboxes. Change the name of the number field to something unique.

`<input name="othername" type="number">`

---

**EDIT**

I have add a bit of jquery so you can see that it is submitting the checkbox's and number field values. There must be something else going on that is not shown in the code you have provided.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
    alert($(this).serialize());
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="paypal">
  <div class="donation_container">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_donations"> 
    <input name="business" type="hidden" value="info@***.org"> 
    <input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="Donation">
    <input name="no_shipping" type="hidden" value="1"> 
    <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1"> 
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD"> 
    <input name="tax" type="hidden" value="0.00"> 
    <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="US"> 
    <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-DonationsBF"> 
    <div class="donate_call_to_action">
      <div class="donate_call_to_action_text">Become ***
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="donation_buttons">
      <label class="donation_label"> 
        <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="1000.00">
        <div>$1000</div>
      </label>
      <label class="donation_label">
        <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="500.00">
        <div>$500</div>
      </label>
      <label class="donation_label">
        <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="100.00">
        <div>$100</div>
      </label>
      <label class="donation_label">
        <input name="amount" type="checkbox" value="50.00">
        <div>$50</div>
      </label>
      <div class="custom_donation">
        <i>$</i>
        <input name="other_amount" type="number">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="donation_button">
    <button type="submit" formmethod="post" class="btn btn-primary" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit">Donate</button> 
    <img src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed the name to "custom_amount". Now the buttons transfer the correct amount, but the input field doesn't send anything.

Comment: @talkinggoat I have updated my answer to show that it should be submitting the all the data. There must be something else going on with your full code.

Comment: There are two things going on, here. 1.) PayPal apparently requires 'name="amount"' to submit the amount, so the custom amount field must contain that, as well as the checkboxes in order to tell PayPal an amount. 2.) when a checkbox is checked, it submits the input form, as well, producing the output amount=50.00&amount= in the alert box. Thus, the $0.00 problem, when using checkboxes.

Comment: You are going to have to create a hidden ammout field and use javascript to populate it with either the selected checkbox or the custom value.